# Get the average of fields in an Array of structs in Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a query similar to this one:

```
    select id, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(name, client_id, locations)) as client,
 from cell_phone_info where ARRAY_LENGTH(locations) > 0 group by id order by id
```

where locations is a array with positional information from the cellphone of the user, usualy this array has 5 elements with speed, latitude and longitude information.

The output is similar to this

id | client.name | client.id | locations.speed | locations.lat | location.lon

1  | Jack | 1 | 0.02 | -40.321624 | -20.32365

++ | ++ |  ++| 0.021 | -40.321624 | -20.32665

++ | ++ |  ++| 0.021 | -40.321624 | -20.32665

++ | ++ |  ++| 0.030 | -40.321624 | -20.32665

++ | ++ |  ++| 0.021 | -40.321624 | -20.32665

1  | Maria | 2 | 0.03 | -40.321624 | -20.32365

++ | ++ |  ++| 0.041 | -42.321624 | -20.32665

++ | ++ |  ++| 0.021 | -42.321624 | -20.32665

++ | ++ |  ++| 0.033 | -42.321624 | -20.32665

++ | ++ |  ++| 0.012 | -42.321624 | -20.32665

I would like to have for each client the average and the standard deviation of the values in the location array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
select id, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(name, client_id, locations,

(select AVG(l.speed) from unnest(locations) l) as average

)) as client,
 from cell_phone_info where ARRAY_LENGTH(locations) > 0 group by id order by id
```